# Acteur global [...] au féminin ?

Tags: accord, constructions

Bonjour,

> L'entreprise est un acteur mondial de la transformation numérique

Doit-on dire : *est une actrice mondiale*.
Ou doit-on laisser le masculin ?

En d'autre terme est-ce que l'expression "être acteur de" (être moteur de) s'accorde-t-elle en genre ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je n'ai jamais vu d'accord en genre avec ***acteur mondial***. On peut considérer qu'on est proche d'une locution ayant un sens particulier, comme peuvent l'être *acteur incontournable*, *acteur majeur*, *acteur mineur*, *acteur essentiel*, *acteur décisif*, *acteur secondaire*, *acteur marginal*, etc.

L'utilisation d'***actrice*** surprendrait car on penserait aussitôt à une femme comédienne, pas à une entreprise.

Cela dit, rien ne dit que l'usage ne pourra pas évoluer dans le futur.